# from origin 'clientUrl' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, regex, reactjs, axios, single-sign-on

UI: reaact.js(axios)
Backend: node/express
Using saml2.js package to access single-sign-on(sso).

Sending request to backend(node.js), in node I am using res.redirect(https://sso:9090), at res.redirect(https://sso:9090) i am getting the below error

```
// Create service provider
var sp_options = {
  entity_id: "https://sp.example.com/metadata.xml",
  private_key: fs.readFileSync("key-file.pem").toString(),
  certificate: fs.readFileSync("cert-file.crt").toString(),
  assert_endpoint: "https://sp.example.com/assert"
};
var sp = new saml2.ServiceProvider(sp_options);

// Create identity provider
var idp_options = {
  sso_login_url: "https://idp.example.com/login",
  sso_logout_url: "https://idp.example.com/logout",
  certificates: [fs.readFileSync("cert-file1.crt").toString(), fs.readFileSync("cert-file2.crt").toString()]
};
var idp = new saml2.IdentityProvider(idp_options);

// ------ Define express endpoints ------

// Endpoint to retrieve metadata
app.get("/metadata.xml", function(req, res) {
  res.type('application/xml');
  res.send(sp.create_metadata());
});

// Starting point for login
app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
  sp.create_login_request_url(idp, {}, function(err, login_url, request_id) {
    if (err != null)
      return res.send(500);
    res.redirect(login_url);
  });
});



// Assert endpoint for when login completes
app.post("/assert", function(req, res) {
  var options = {request_body: req.body};
  sp.post_assert(idp, options, function(err, saml_response) {
    if (err != null)
      return res.send(500);
    // Save name_id and session_index for logout
    // Note:  In practice these should be saved in the user session, not globally.
    name_id = saml_response.user.name_id;
    session_index = saml_response.user.session_index;
    res.send("Login Sucessfull");
  });
});
```

Error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sso:9090' (redirected from 'https://api.com/login') from origin 'http://client:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Use the cors middleware for express to handle those issues for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors its the state of the art solution for CORS policy handling.

Comment: THanks, but the issue here is I am able to access api end points from UI but not to the sso from resp.redirect(url) in node.js. res.redirect(login_url); you could see this in my code